# error when calling data from created_at using where

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, php-carbon

hey so im trying to display a graph based on selected from and to from user.
the column that it will call is from `created_at` column but when i write my code like

```html
$email = count(DiraResponses::where('company_id', $companyID)->where('created_at', '>=', $request->from)->where('created_at', '<=', $request->to)->where('type', 'email')->where('format', 'email')->get());
```

it returns an error
`FatalThrowableError in FileSessionHandler.php line 70:
Call to undefined method Carbon\Carbon::getTimestamp()`

how should i solve this? this error comes only when i call the created_at column.

Comment: I don't think the code snippet actually has anything to do with that error. That method in `FileSessionHandler` is pretty self-contained, and looks more like an issue with the Carbon library. Can you provide your Laravel version number, maybe PHP version, things like that?

Answer (score 1):

Try using whereDate() function while comparing dates like this.

```
whereDate('created_at', '>=', $request->from)->whereDate('created_at', '<=', $request->to)
```

Also don't forgot to format your comparison date same as your database formate for example

```
$from = date('Y-m-d' , strtotime($request->from));
```

And then pass $from in the query

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following syntax to get count.

```
$email = DiraResponses::
    where([['company_id', $companyID],
    ['created_at', '>=', $request->from],
    ['created_at', '<=', $request->to],
    ['type', 'email'],
    ['format', 'email']])
    ->count();
```